# Fieldtype to overlay html (tooltips) on top of image?

Tags: ee2

I would love to find a fieldtype addon that enables me to add tooltips onto an image, like the example here: http://goo.gl/kkLXoZ

Basically a very simple editor that enabled you to select an image and create/edit/delete tooltips on a particular coordinate relative to the image container size. I haven’t seen this on devotee or elsewhere - thought I would try my luck here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Only [Pointee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pointee) exist. But is not support multi points.

Comment: I haven't used that addon but a brief look says you can have multiple instance on the same publish page so perhaps you could accomplish what you want by using it within a grid or matrix field. They would have to add the same image on each line but you could record the new co-ords that way and have another column for the text you would like to use for that co-ord.

Comment: is no grid or matrix support for this field.

Comment: send me message to max at eec.ms and I will send you one of my add-ons for this (in beta now)